# Can't add in Firebase when authentified Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can't add a comment in firebase when I am authentified.

There is my rules.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
}
```

My activity where I test if user is not null before push in firebase.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String baseUrl = "url";
        final Firebase fb = new Firebase(baseUrl+"/comments");
        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);
        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(user != null)
                    fb.push().child("comment").setValue(et.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Error** *I get in log*

> W/RepoOperation: setValue at /comments/-L0shVMfCJWab7_5ltnO/comment failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied

When I change the rule of write to true, it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem, instead use Firebase Instance I use DatabaseReference.

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String baseUrl = "https://tpdevproject.firebaseio.com/";
    final DatabaseReference fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("comments");
    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(user != null)
                    fb.push().child("comment").setValue(et.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both rules are true in firebase console-:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to specify that how can you write values to firebase if you have not set it to true.Specifying true means you have permission to write

Comment: What I mean it is to read data without authentication and write data just if user is authentified (for more security).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
}
```

Note the `!==` in the write rule, with two equals signs instead of one.

This answer is based on some examples in the [Firebase documentation on User Based Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Comment: Don't work. I found the solution, instead use Firebase I use DatabaseRefernce.